How to Deploy a Safe Wallet in a Deterministic Way Depending on User EOA Address?
I'm working on deploying a Safe Wallet using the Safe Protocol Kit and Ethers.js. My goal is to deploy the Safe Wallet in a deterministic way based on the user's EOA (Externally Owned Account) address.
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { EthersAdapter } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import SafeApiKit from "@safe-global/api-kit";
import { SafeFactory } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import { SafeAccountConfig } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";

dotenv.config();

const deployWallet = async (
  _rpcUrl: string,
  _chainId: bigint,
  _scannerUrl: string,
  _notaryRecoveryPk: string,
  userEOA: string
) => {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(_rpcUrl);
    const notaryRecovery = new ethers.Wallet(_notaryRecoveryPk, provider);

    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
      ethers,
      signerOrProvider: notaryRecovery,
    });

    const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter });

    const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
      owners: [await notaryRecovery.getAddress(), userEOA],
      threshold: 1,
    };

    const protocolKit = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig });
    const safeAddress = await protocolKit.getAddress();

    console.log(`Your Safe has been deployed: ${_scannerUrl + safeAddress}`);

    return safeAddress;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

const rpcUrl = process.env.RPC_URL_SEPOLIA;
const scannerUrl = process.env.SCANNER_URL_SEPOLIA;
const notaryRecoveryPk = process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY;

export const deployWalletAddress = async (userEOA: string) => {
  return deployWallet(rpcUrl, 11155111n, scannerUrl, notaryRecoveryPk, userEOA);
};

My Questions:
How can I ensure the Safe Wallet deployment is deterministic based on the user EOA address?
Are there any specific configurations or parameters I should adjust in the SafeFactory or SafeAccountConfig to achieve determinism?
Is there a better approach or best practice for deploying a Safe Wallet in a deterministic manner?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Thanks for your question. Safe natively derives the address of a safe from the input parameters used during it's initial creation. This means that given the exact same parameters (including saltNonce), the derived address will always be the same.
Now, this is only true with notable exceptions: on most Layer 2 networks, the contract used to create Safes is different; it will always give the same address in a deterministic way, but this address will be different than the one derived on Layer 1s. The second exception concerns all networks that are not EVM-compatible. In this second case, the address will still be deterministic, but again, will provide a different address than on Layer 1s and Layer 2s.
Please let me know if it answered your question 
Best, Louis

thanks for that answer. it did provide me with some details i was not aware of. i have learned a lot about the ecosystem in the past weeks. two more related questions: what is needed to make a deployed safe wallet f.ex. on sepolia "show up" automatically in https://app.safe.global . does polygon mainnet (not zk) count as L1/L2?

also kind of a weird observation: when running safe wallet inside docker, a "windows" instance will lead to different addresses then a linux/macos, because CRLF/ LF issues
